# Increase Multi-touch points

Tags: multi-touch

I have an Infocus M2 running Android 4.4. It supports only two finger multi-touch, which causes problems with some games. Is there any way to increase the number of touch points it can recognize?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot increase touch points as this is related to your hardware (screen) not the software. You would need to purchase a new screen for your device that supports multi-touch features.